# How to implement direct message using twitter API in c#?

Tags: c#, twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to access direct messages using Twitter API.
What do we require to fetch direct message like URL, Header, type of authentication?

```
var fullUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/events/list.json";
            var _timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
            var timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(_timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            var _oauthNonce = Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(
                 DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

            // Add all the OAuth headers we'll need to use when constructing the hash.
            Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            data.Add("oauth_consumer_key", consumerKey);
            data.Add("oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1");
            data.Add("oauth_timestamp", timestamp);
            data.Add("oauth_nonce", _oauthNonce);
            data.Add("oauth_token", accessToken);
            data.Add("oauth_version", "1.0");

            // Generate the OAuth signature and add it to our payload.
            data.Add("oauth_signature", GenerateSignature(fullUrl, data));

            // Build the OAuth HTTP Header from the data.
            string oAuthHeader = GenerateOAuthHeader(data);

            using (var http = new HttpClient())
            {
                http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", oAuthHeader);

                var httpResp = await http.GetAsync(fullUrl);
                var respBody = await httpResp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return respBody;
            }
```

but getting "Authorization required response".

Comment: Is this not just an exercise in reading their documentation? https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/direct-messages/api-features

Comment: Direct messages require user authentication (3-legged OAuth)

Comment: In twitter documentation, i am not able to understand what i have missed in code. Is any header missing or any parameters

Comment: Did you figure this out?I am having the same issue; when I sent other requests as POST and adding "Authorization" to the header with the oAUTH Header string it works; but not with GET.

Comment: Can you post your GenerateSignature and GenerateOAuthHeader methods?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow instructions here.
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/authorizing-a-request

Specially, when creating signature, your question doesn't have the code for creating signature.

Follow this for it
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/creating-a-signature

If you use correct values, then there is no issue in your code.